# Unable to capture city, and country values from Facebook iOS SDK in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I am currently using the Facebook iOS SDK to capture email, first, and last name successfully in my app.  However, for some reason, I am having difficulty capturing the location information such as city, and country for the user.

Here is my relevant code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        fbLoginButton.delegate = self
        fbLoginButton.readPermissions = ["email", "public_profile", "user_location"]
}

extension RegisterViewController: FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        print("Did log out of facebook")
    }

    func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        print("Successfully logged in with facebook...")
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, email, location{location}"]).start { (connection, result, err) in

            if err != nil {
                print("Failed to start graph request:", err)
                return
            }

            print(result)

            let fbDetails = result as! NSDictionary
            let location : NSDictionary! = fbDetails.value(forKey: "location") as! NSDictionary //code crashes here
            let locationContents : NSDictionary! = location.value(forKey: "location") as! NSDictionary
            let city: String! = locationContents.value(forKey: "city") as? String
            let state: String! = locationContents.value(forKey: "state") as? String
            let country: String! = locationContents.value(forKey: "country") as? String

            print(fbDetails)
            print("city:", city)
            print("state:", state)
            print("country:", country)


        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code, in my console, I see the output for email, first_name, last_name, id, name, but nothing for location, and my app crashes with:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

when it reaches the line:

```
let location : NSDictionary! = fbDetails.value(forKey: "location") as! NSDictionary
```

Can anyone see what it is I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The thing that is leading directly to the crash is that you are force-unwrapping an optional value. As to why you can't get those values; privacy permissions?

Comment: How should I be unwrapping the optional value, and how can I check to see if my privacy permissions are properly set?

Comment: You should say something like `if let city = locationContents.value(forKey: "city") as? String { //Do something with city } `.  For permissions, see the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add 'user_location' to your read_permission.

```
fbLoginButton.readPermissions = ["email", "public_profile", "user_location"]
```

Remember to verify this permission in your fb application.(user_location is not default allowed permissions)

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, and my apologies for the delay in getting back to you.  I have made the appropriate changes to my code, and unfortunately, I'm still not getting the location details in the response.  I have tried to delete the app from my Facebook profile each time I make changes to the code in order to go through the "handshake" process fresh, and unfortunately, I'm still not receiving the values.  I'm wondering if I need to make changes to my privacy settings in my personal fb page, but not sure what I need to do, if anything.

Comment: The 'location' data is from your fb profile 'about' -> 'Place You've lived' -> 'Current City'. Make sure your profile contain this information. I test to change this information and login again, then i got different location data.
Make sure your 'location' permission verified or you're login with administrator account of your fb application.

Comment: To get permission of user_location, start a submission of 'user_location' in your fb application. 'developers.facebook.com'->'App Review'->'Submit Items for Approval'